# Get qlr to use only features in same folder

Tags: qgis, qlr

Today I have a startup-qgz with the wms-layers I need, but there is 30 shapefiles that I have to add to all projects and I have used the qlr to add them all.

The shapefiles always have the same names, and I use to copy all qml+qlr to the new folder but when I load the qlr it uses the shapefiles in the last folder. Right now I solve this by moving the old folder and when QGIS asks where the files are I point at the new one

Is there a way to get qlr to use the shapefiles in the folder where it is positioned or some other way to do the startup quicker? Or is qlr the wrong way if you want to copy your normal startup-setting.